# Input Field Disappers When Selecting Date From DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a `datepicker` which only allows a user to select a month and year (this bit works fine) but when I select a month and close the picker, the `input` field adds the following class but I don't know why or how to stop this

`style="display: none"`

**HTML**

`<input class="form-control" type="date" id="date">`

**JQuery**

```
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();

$(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker({
        format: "MM yyyy",
        minViewMode: 1,
        startDate: new Date(year, month, '01'),
        endDate: new Date(year + 1, month, '31')
    });
});
```

**HTML when field clicked and picker displayed**

`<input class="form-control" type="date" id="date" style="display: block;">`

**HTML after selection made**

`<input class="form-control" type="date" id="date" style="display: none;">`

I tried the following but this doesn't seem to work

```
   var date = new Date();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();

    $(function () {
        $("#date").datepicker({
            format: "MM yyyy",
            minViewMode: 1,
            startDate: new Date(year, month, '01'),
            endDate: new Date(year + 1, month, '31'),
            onSelect: function() {
                document.getElementById("date").style.display = "block !important";
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: reproduce the issue on fiddle

Comment: That's weird. Are you willing to reproduce this on a fiddle?

Comment: @Patel No I cant reproduce the issue in fiddle

Comment: its working as intended here, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/tuG6C/995/

Comment: @dreamweiver as per my other comment, I already new it worked in fiddle

Comment: how are you closing the picker as you said `when I select a month and close the picker` , just clicking on other space right ?. And try this  remove class `form-control` and change input type to text and check. some other JS  may be hiding your div `onchange` of `input[type=date]/.form-control`

Comment: Hmm I didn't notice your comment before posting mine,anyway I feel there is something else on your view model which is causing this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be that the following script in my Site.Master was causing the issue.  Once removed it worked fine.

I added this from another issue I had but when I removed this issue and the issue I had when I needed the below `script` still work so got rid of it

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`